# Docker build and push using github: invalid reference format

Tags: docker, github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I want to build my image and push it to dockerhub using github actions.This is [my repo](https://github.com/ehsansh84/ehsan)

And this is how I want to do my job:

```
name: ci

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'master'

jobs:
  docker:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      -
        name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      -
        name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v1
      -
        name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1
      -
        name: Login to DockerHub
        uses: docker/login-action@v1
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD }}
      -
        name: Build and push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          context: .
          load: true
          tags: shirzadi/ehsan:latest
      -
        name: Push it!
        run: docker push ${{ env.IMAGE }}:${{ env.GIT_SHA }}
```

And this is the result:
[image: invalid reference format]

Comment: Where do `env.IMAGE` and `env.GIT_SHA` come from ?

Comment: @AymDev I thought those are predefined variables by github
What should I put there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using environment variables that don't exist. According to [docker/build-push-action@v2](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action) documentation it can build, tag and push your image in a single step:

```yaml
jobs:
  docker:
    steps:
      # ...
      -
        name: Build and push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          context: .
          push: true
          tags: shirzadi/ehsan:latest,shirzadi/ehsan:${{ env.GITHUB_SHA }}
```

> The `tags` key lists 2 tags and use the `GITHUB_SHA` environment variable. These tags will be pushed as the `push` key is set to true.

See:

- [Github Actions - Default environment variables](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables#default-environment-variables)
- [docker/build-push-action@v2 - customizing inputs](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action#inputs)

Comment: Error: buildx failed with: error: push and load may not be set together at the moment

Comment: @ehsanshirzadi Do you need to use this `load` option ? I'm not sure to understand its purpose. If it generates a tarball of your image that you don't use, just remove it.

Answer (score 1):

You are not having env.IMAGE data. Below piece of code should do the job.

```yaml
      - name: Build and push
        run: docker build -t ${{ env.IMAGE }}:${{ github.sha }} .
        env:
          IMAGE: shirzadi/ehsan
           

      - name: Push it!
        run: docker push ${{ env.IMAGE }}:${{ github.sha }}
        env:
          IMAGE: shirzadi/ehsan
```

Comment: An error says: Unrecognized named-value: 'IMAGE' => 
run: docker push ${{ IMAGE }}:${{ GIT_SHA }}

Comment: I have edited my answer, I had missed a small thing. Please check with updated answer ?